# In satisfiability, what is the difference between the empty clause and the empty clause set?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

The empty clause is a clause containing no literals and by definition is false: $c = \{\} = F$

What then is the empty clause set, and why does it evaluate to true?

Comment: The empty set does not exist in propositional logic, so your question doesn't really make sense...

Comment: I perhaps should give some more context. I am studying satisfiability. Let F be a clause-set (a conjunction of clauses). If the empty clause belongs to F then F is unsatisfiable. If F is the empty set then F is satisfiable. I think I am confused about the scenarios where F contains only one clause; the empty clause, and when F has no clauses. Why is the first unsatisfiable (i.e. false) but the second satisfiable (true)?

Comment: I have updated the title, thanks.

Comment: Are your clauses supposed to be in disjunctive normal form, perhaps? Then the empty clause is false because $\bot \lor p = p$ always. Whereas $\top \land p = p$ always, so the empty set is always satisfiable.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you! Would you like to convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? If not, I'll type it up and give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember, we take the disjunction over the elements of a *clause*, then the conjunction over the entire *clause set*.  So if a *clause* is empty we take the empty *disjunction*, and if the entire *clause set* is empty we take the empty *conjunction*.

What does it mean to take an empty disjunction or empty conjunction?  Let's consider a similar situation.  Over the real numbers, what is an empty sum, or an empty product?  I claim that an empty sum should be $0$; an empty product should be $1$.  Why is this?  Clearly, we have:

sum($2,3,4$) + sum($5,6,7$) = sum($2,3,4,5,6,7$)

sum($2,3,4$) + sum($5,6$) = sum($2,3,4,5,6$)

sum($2,3,4$) + sum($5$) = sum($2,3,4,5$)

Now make the second sum empty:

sum($2,3,4$) + sum() = sum($2,3,4$)

So sum() should be $0$.  In the same way, product() must be $1$.  (You can see this by replacing "sum" by "product" and "+" by "$\times$" in the lines above.)

In general, a commutative, associative binary operation applied on an empty set should be the identity element for that operation.

Now back to your original example.

Since the identity for disjunction is "false" (because `false OR x = x` and `x OR false = x` for any `x`), an empty *clause* is false.

Since the identity for conjunction is "true" (because `true AND x = x` and `x AND true = x` for any `x`), an empty *clause set* is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an intuition why this is so by observing that:

1. A disjunction is true iff there exists a member which is true. In an empty disjunction (empty clause) there is no such member, so it is always false.
2. A conjunction is true iff no member which is false exists. An empty conjunction (empty set in cnf problems) has no member (and a fortiori no member which is false) so it is always true.

It is a similar intuition to the idea of universal quantification being true on the empty domain.